# What is the most common day of week?

Tags: r

I'm learning R and I have little to no technical background. I have a table with start times and end times column and I need to find the most common day of the week, I'm guessing by extracting the day of the week first and then finding the median of those columns. I'm guessing those are the columns I need, since the rest are irrelevant.
[Table, the title of whose columns are "X, Start.Time,  End.Time,   Trip.Duration   Start.Station,  End.Station,    User.Type,  Gender, and Birth.Year."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i5Nj.png)

This was the code I came up with:

```
ny = read.csv('new_york_city.csv')
head(ny)
table(ny$Start.Time)
table(ny$End.Time)

ny.Start.Date <- (table(format(ny$Start.Time, '%A')))
ny.End.Date <- (table(format(ny$End.Time, '%A')))

df2 <- data.frame(ny.Start.Date, ny.End.Date)

apply(df2, 2, median)

order(data.frame, decreasing = TRUE)

reduce(rbind, by (ny.Start.Date, ny.End.Date["group"], head, n = 1))
```

Apparently, something is wrong, but I don't know what. Would appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your error message and your data? Then it will be easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can either use `Start.Time` or `End.Time` column here, extract the week day using `weekdays`, count their occurrence with `table`, `sort` them and select the first entry.

```
most_common_day <- sort(table(weekdays(ny$Start.Time)), decreasing = TRUE)[1]
```